# Integrating default CDT editor into an eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-cdt

Iam developing an eclipse based plugin and trying to intergrate it with eclipse. The plugin reads an xml file and displays the contents in a tree viewer. The xml file hold the informations related to a C/C++ source files as well as its include files. I have loaded everything to a tree viewer. Now I would like to show the default CDT editor when a file is selected. How can I achieve this.

And moreover, I would also like to get the content assistance as eclipse provides for the functions defined in the same file as well as include files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define own Editor and make it `extends` CDT Editor, need to check plugin is and add to 'Require-Bundle: ' in MANIFEST.MF

If CDT content assistance is not enough, you are to redefine your own.